# Git - switch between tags

Tags: git, svn, tags, git-checkout

I'm having trouble to switch between tags in git like in subversion.
In subversion a tag is like a branch a new commit. So i simply have to call

```
svn co https://example.com/tags/1.0.0 exampledir to get a tag.
```

If i want to switch to version 1.0.1 i simple call in the exampledir

```
svn switch https://example.com/tags/1.0.1
```

I switched successfully to the new tag without changes on new files.

On git a tag is not a branch, it's an alias to a commit. If i clone a repository

```
git clone https://github.com/opencart/opencart.git
```

I'll get the master by default. When i checkout a tag (no matter if i use the master or create a new branch with -b option

```
git checkout -b 2.0.0.0 2.0.0.0
```

I get the tag, but also uncommited changes (maybe changes from master to this tag?)
And now, i can't switch to another tag like 2.0.1.0 without purge this changes or force the
checkout.... 
The reasion why i'm asking is that i want to use the application but don't want to upgrade manually... so i only want to switch from tag to tag if a new version is out...

Comment: The `git checkout` approach is the correct one. Try stashing the uncommited changes.

Comment: The problem is with the line endings. When you look at `git diff` you'll see the warnings. Unfortunately I don't know how to handle that properly. Look for other posts on this site.